# White line under navigation bar when scrolling or until pressing on the search bar

Tags: swift, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, uisearchbar

As you can see in the video, there is a white thin line under the navigation bar the moment i start scrolling.

It would only disappear when I would press on the searchBar (contained by my searchController, so the search bar is not added from the Storyboard). I tried a lot of different combinations in order to try to make it disappear but nothing worked.

Any help is appreciated! Thanks!

**Video:** https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KcgZmBg1VS0

This is the code inside my `viewDidLoad`:

```
searchController.searchBar.delegate = self

searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false
searchController.searchBar.placeholder = "Search for a recipe"

searchController.searchBar.barTintColor = navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor
searchController.searchBar.tintColor = UIColor.white
```

Comment: This white line problem is a bug, even in the latest iOS 12 beta. Disabling translucency of the navigation bar helps, but this has impact on the UI and scrollview behaviour.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to set background color and change shadow of the `navigationBar`. It possibly connected with `navigationBar`.

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), forBarMetrics: UIBarMetrics.Default)
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
```

Try to add this line:

```
searchController.searchBar.backgroundColor = navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor
```

In the file `setupSearchBar()`

After code fix:

[image]

Comment: @TomaRadu-Petrescu I will create test project and try to see what is going on

Comment: That would be great :) Thanks!

Comment: @TomaRadu-Petrescu I create a small project with searchController and do not receive this behavior. So this could be connected with our navigation bar. Could you please share code with navigation bar customization

Comment: @TomaRadu-Petrescu i add small code fix that should fix behavior.

Comment: Wow! It solved the problem. Thanks a lot for your time and the answer!!!

Comment: @TomaRadu-Petrescu nice to help.

Comment: Here is my code: and this is still not fixing my white line when the searchBar is animated to visible:
excuse my code formatting..
    //white line flash fix

    _searchController.searchBar.layer.borderWidth = 0.0;
    _searchController.searchBar.layer.borderColor = [self.navigationController.navigationBar.barTintColor CGColor];
    [self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackIndicatorImage:[UIImage new]];
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.shadowImage = [UIImage new];
    _searchController.searchBar.backgroundColor = self.navigationController.navigationBar.barTintColor;

Answer (score -1):

You can remove that shadow below your navigation bar by the way. I have created extension for doing this:

```
extension UINavigationBar {

  func shouldRemoveShadow(_ value: Bool) -> Void {
    self.setValue(value, forKey: "hidesShadow")
  }
}
```

Comment: I haven’t verified what you typed at all, but I wanted to point out that the `if` is pointless. You already have a Boolean, so use it as an argument to `setValue`! The body of this method could simply be 1 line instead of 5: `self.setValue(value, forKey: "hidesShadow")`